# How can I fix onmouseLeave triggering onmouseEnter on DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I have build the below CSS/Jquery script that on mouseenter scales the DIV and change a font awesome icon to some text when mouseEnter´s, and should change the back to the icon on mouseLeave, but for some reasson I can see in the console that when I remove the mouse from the DIV it rigth after triggers mouseEnter, which leaves the text in the DIV instead of changing back to the icon.

As you can see in my below script I have also experimented with .hover instead of .mouseenter/.mouseleave, but it gives the same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
$('#SystemInfodiv1').hover(
  function() {
    console.log("mouseenter")
    $(this).find("#SystemInfodiv1").removeClass("pulse red");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").removeClass("SystemInfoText");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").addClass("SystemInfoText2");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").html("<div>Last Backup:</div><div>10-10-2200&nbsp;<font style='font-size: 3px;'>(<em><b>89</b> timer siden</em>)</font></div>");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("mouseleave")
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").html("<i class='fas fa-database'></i>");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").removeClass("SystemInfoText2");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").addClass("SystemInfoText");
  }
);


$("#SystemInfodiv2").mouseenter(function() {
  console.log("mouseenter")
  $("#SystemInfoText2").removeClass("SystemInfoText");
  $("#SystemInfoText2").addClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html("<div>DB HDD Størrelse:</div><div><b>666</b> af <b>888</b> brugt&nbsp;<font style='font-size: 3px;'>(<em><b>87%</b> fri</em>)</font></div>");
});
$("#SystemInfodiv2").mouseleave(function() {
  console.log("mouseleave")
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html().remove
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html("<i class='far fa-hdd'></i>").fadeIn('slow');
  $("#SystemInfoText2").removeClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText2").addClass("SystemInfoText");
});

$("#SystemInfodiv3").mouseenter(function() {
  console.log("mouseenter")
  $("#SystemInfodiv3").removeClass("pulse red");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").removeClass("SystemInfoText");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").addClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").html("<div>Sidste synk mod AD:</div><div><b><span id='ADUserSyncLastRun'></span></b>&nbsp;<font style='font-size: 3px;'>(<em><b><span id='ADUserSyncMinutesSince'></span></b> min. siden</em>)</font></div>");
});
$("#SystemInfodiv3").mouseleave(function() {
  console.log("mouseleave")
  $("#SystemInfoText3").html("<i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").removeClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").addClass("SystemInfoText");
});
```

```css
#SystemInfoTable {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 190px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.SystemInfodiv {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition-property: width height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
}

.SystemInfodiv:hover {
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: scale(4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 101;
}

.SystemInfoText {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  z-index: 101;
}

.SystemInfoText2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 4px;
  top: 13px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 101;
}

.pulse.red {
  background: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  animation: pulse-red 2s infinite;
}

.pulse.yellow {
  background: rgba(222, 168, 6, 1);
  animation: pulse-yellow 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse-red {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse-yellow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(222, 168, 6, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(222, 168, 6, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(222, 168, 6, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://colorlib.com/polygon/concept/assets/vendor/fonts/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SystemInfoTable">
  <div id="SystemInfodiv1" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText1" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
  <div id="SystemInfodiv2" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText2" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="far fa-hdd" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
  <div id="SystemInfodiv3" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText3" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this issue because of your div height, when you leave a div you enter in another div. I have added 10px height more for  `.SystemInfodiv:hover`

```
.SystemInfodiv:hover { height: 35px }
```

and 10px top more for `.SystemInfoText2`

```
.SystemInfoText2 { top: 23px }
```

```js
$('#SystemInfodiv1').hover(
  function() {
    console.log("mouseenter")
    $(this).find("#SystemInfodiv1").removeClass("pulse red");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").removeClass("SystemInfoText");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").addClass("SystemInfoText2");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").html("<div>Last Backup:</div><div>10-10-2200&nbsp;<font style='font-size: 3px;'>(<em><b>89</b> timer siden</em>)</font></div>");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("mouseleave")
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").html("<i class='fas fa-database'></i>");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").removeClass("SystemInfoText2");
    $(this).find("#SystemInfoText1").addClass("SystemInfoText");
  }
);


$("#SystemInfodiv2").mouseenter(function() {
  console.log("mouseenter")
  $("#SystemInfoText2").removeClass("SystemInfoText");
  $("#SystemInfoText2").addClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html("<div>DB HDD Størrelse:</div><div><b>666</b> af <b>888</b> brugt&nbsp;<font style='font-size: 3px;'>(<em><b>87%</b> fri</em>)</font></div>");
});
$("#SystemInfodiv2").mouseleave(function() {
  console.log("mouseleave")
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html().remove
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html("<i class='far fa-hdd'></i>").fadeIn('slow');
  $("#SystemInfoText2").removeClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText2").addClass("SystemInfoText");
});

$("#SystemInfodiv3").mouseenter(function() {
  console.log("mouseenter")
  $("#SystemInfodiv3").removeClass("pulse red");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").removeClass("SystemInfoText");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").addClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").html("<div>Sidste synk mod AD:</div><div><b><span id='ADUserSyncLastRun'></span></b>&nbsp;<font style='font-size: 3px;'>(<em><b><span id='ADUserSyncMinutesSince'></span></b> min. siden</em>)</font></div>");
});
$("#SystemInfodiv3").mouseleave(function() {
  console.log("mouseleave")
  $("#SystemInfoText3").html("<i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").removeClass("SystemInfoText2");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").addClass("SystemInfoText");
});
```

```css
#SystemInfoTable {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 190px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.SystemInfodiv {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition-property: width height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
}

.SystemInfodiv:hover {
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  transform: scale(4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 101;
}

.SystemInfoText {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  z-index: 101;
}

.SystemInfoText2 {
  position: relative; 
  font-size: 4px;
  top: 23px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 101;
  height: 100px;
}

.pulse.red {
  background: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  animation: pulse-red 2s infinite;
}

.pulse.yellow {
  background: rgba(222, 168, 6, 1);
  animation: pulse-yellow 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse-red {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse-yellow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(222, 168, 6, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(222, 168, 6, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(222, 168, 6, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://colorlib.com/polygon/concept/assets/vendor/fonts/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SystemInfoTable">
  <div id="SystemInfodiv1" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText1" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
  <div id="SystemInfodiv2" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText2" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="far fa-hdd" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
  <div id="SystemInfodiv3" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText3" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
</div>
```